# Is there any security issue while two different process using different hard link of same file?

Tags: linux, storage, file-system, process

To reduce disk space I have planned to use a hard link instead of full copy, Is there any security issue while two different processes using different hard links of the same executable file as base?

Comment: You may as well say "use the same file", because that's what a hard link is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not uncommon especially for software for embedded systems (BusyBox etc) to have a single binary which has everything in it and then to hard link this binary to different names in order to provide the expected command names. This approach by itself is not a problem: while the different invocations of the binary will share read-only (or execute-only) code and data segments they will all have their own read-write stack and heap, strictly separated from the rest as with different binaries.